# Can't install Xamarin on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I trying to install Xamarin studio on Mac OS X.

I running installer, select all that I need and click next.

Installer downloading about 16MB and than it stop downloading.

After 5 minutes it shows error and suggest manual installation.

Maybe someone had this error too, how I can solve it.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: that error dialog explains exactly what you need to do to complete the installation manually

Comment: okay. But  why it can't install automatically?